# Как передать управляемый многомерный массив в метод управляемого класса C++/CLI

Tags: .net, excel, c++-cli

Имеется многомерный управляемый массив, содержащий диапазоны ячеек Excel. Его нужно передать в метод класса, чтобы метод получил доступ к записи данных в ячейки.

Вот массив:

```
array <Range^,3>^ oRange = gcnew array<Range^, 3>(31, 6, 1);
```

Вот фрагмент его инициализации:

```
oRange[0, 0, 0] = oSheet->Range["D3", "D3"]; //Формат
oRange[0, 1, 0] = oSheet->Range["E3", "F3"]; //Зона
oRange[0, 2, 0] = oSheet->Range["G3", "H3"]; //Поз.
oRange[0, 3, 0] = oSheet->Range["I3", "M3"]; //Обозначение
oRange[0, 4, 0] = oSheet->Range["N3", "S3"]; //Наименование
oRange[0, 5, 0] = oSheet->Range["T3", "T3"]; //Кол-во
oRange[0, 6, 0] = oSheet->Range["U3", "V3"]; //Примеч.
```

Вот прототип метода класса:

```
void Print(int& int_Index, int& int_Position, array <Range^, 3 > ^ oRange);
```

При попытке вызова метода класса пишет ошибку:

```
Strip1->Print(0, 4, oRange);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка не в передаче массива, а в том, что вы передаете rvalue в lvalue reference параметр.

Вот так должен выглядеть прототип функции:

```
void Print(const int& int_Index, const int& int_Position, array <Range^, 3 > ^ oRange);
```